# How to Check for Array Duplicates in C

Tags: c, arrays, merge, duplicates

The aim of my C program is to take two arrays (both comprised of unique numbers) and merge the two of them into a new array, eliminating any numbers that are the same between both of them. However, when I try to merge the two, it instead prints back both arrays combined without eliminating any duplicates.

My program creates "array_C" by first adding in the elements from "array_A". Afterwards, it checks if there are duplicates between "array_B" and "array_C" using a counter variable. For every value in "array_C" that the for loop checks, if the value of "array_B" is not equal to the value in "array_C", the counter decreases by 1. If after all the values in "array_C" are checked, the counter is <= 0, that means there are no duplicates of that value in "array_C", and it should be added to the end of "array_C". I keep track of this using a "position" variable.

```
        //Creation of array_C

        int length_C = length_A + length_B;
        int array_C[length_C];

        //Copying array_A to array_C

        for (i = 0; i < length_A; i++) {
          array_C[i] = array_A[i];
        }

        //Checking array_C against array_B for duplicates

        counter = length_A;
        int position = length_A;
        for (i = 0; i < length_B; i++) {
          for (j = 0; j < length_C; j++) {
            if (array_B[i] != array_C[j]) {
              counter--;
            } else {
              counter++;
            }
          }

          //this is the position tracker to add new value in array_C
          if (counter <= 0) {
            array_C[position] = array_B[i];
            position++;
          }
        }
```

If I entered this:

```
Enter the length of array 1: 6
Enter the elements of the array: 1 2 3 4 5 6
Enter the length of array 2: 6
Enter the elements of the array: 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

I expect the results should look like this:

```
Here is the merged array:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

But instead, it looks like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

So apparently something is going wrong and it is not understanding that it should only add variables that are not duplicates.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is flawed. That's why you are getting unexpected outcome. See the following revision in your code:

```
for (i = 0; i < length_B; i++) {
      int skip = 0;
      for (j = 0; j < length_C; j++) {
        if (array_B[i] == array_C[j]) {
          skip=1;
          break;
        } 
      }

      if(skip == 1) continue;
      array_C[position++] = array_B[i];
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for correcting me on my logic error. The code works fine now. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is with the logic inside your inner for loop. according to the problem statement if any value of array_c matches with any value of array_b you should get rid of that value otherwise add the value to array_c. so you can simply try doing the following. please make sure you understand the code. if you have any question feel free to ask.

```
   for (i = 0; i < length_B; i++) {
      bool isExistInArrayC = false;
      for (j = 0; j < length_C; j++) {
        if (array_B[i] == array_C[j]) {
          isExistInArrayC = true;
          break;
        } 
      }

      //this is the position tracker to add new value in array_C
      if (isExistInArrayC == false) {
        array_C[position] = array_B[i];
        position++;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. It didn't occur to me to try to use boolean variables to solve this problem, but your provided solution is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestions will certainly work, but performance (especially with large size arrays) will be very poor. I would maintain a sorted array "C" and do a binary search into it when adding integers from array B.
You'll need a double-linked list for array C of course.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I am still new to the C language and understand it requires a lot of performance optimization so I appreciate the insight.